# What is the easiest way to generate a script to drop and create all objects in a database?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm used to working with SQL Server and the SQL Server Management Studio has the option to automatically generate a script to drop and recreate everything in a database (tables/views/procedures/etc). I find that when developing a new application and writing a bunch of junk in a local database for basic testing it's very helpful to have the options to just nuke the whole thing and recreate it in a clean slate, so I'm looking for a similar functionality within postgres/pgadmin.

PGAdmin has an option to generate a create script for a specific table but right clicking each table would be very tedious and I'm wondering if there's another way to do it.

Comment: [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). If you want just the schema then `-s`/`--schema-only`.

Comment: Forgot to add `--clean`. Read the docs for how this differs between custom and plain text dumps.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that's pretty much what I was looking for, thanks. Don't you want to make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recreate a clean schema only database you can use the [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) client included with a Postgres server install. The options to use are:

> -c

> --clean

> Output commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to outputting the commands for creating them. (Unless --if-exists is also specified, restore might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

> This option is ignored when emitting an archive (non-text) output file. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore.

and:

> -s

> --schema-only

> Dump only the object definitions (schema), not data.

> This option is the inverse of --data-only. It is similar to, but for historical reasons not identical to, specifying --section=pre-data --section=post-data.

> (Do not confuse this with the --schema option, which uses the word “schema” in a different meaning.)

> To exclude table data for only a subset of tables in the database, see --exclude-table-data.

Answer (score -1):

## `clean` in Flyway

The [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) offers a [`clean`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/clean) command that drops all objects in the configured schemas.

To quote the documentation:

> Clean is a great help in development and test. It will effectively give you a fresh start, by wiping your configured schemas completely clean. All objects (tables, views, procedures, …) will be dropped.
>
> Needless to say: do not use against your production DB!